# ~たい次第 expression meaning

Tags: grammar

What does the grammar expression ~たい次第{しだい} mean

For example:

次回の集まりをお誘いいただきたい次第です。

Comment: @virmaior Ah, yes there should. Well spotted! Edited

Comment: What are you trying to say by 「集まりをお誘いいただきたい」?

Comment: As @chocolate is asking, the sentence makes almost no sense as-is.  Why is 「を」 being used?

Comment: @l'électeur This was the sentence that I received (i.e. not written by me) from a Japanese person. Which is why I am asking for, I only substituted 集まり for a different equivalent word.

Comment: @l'électeur The actual sentence received was "次回のライドをお誘いただきたい次第です。".

Comment: @paullb I don't think his statement is particularly rude more than it is a  disagreement with the grammaticality of the sentence. If the sentence is grammatically strange, then it follows that the answers might only cater to the strangeness instead of what reality is.

Comment: Oh.. 　My English is not good enough to see whether @l'électeur's comment was impolite or not but, all I can say here is that  the original sentence is not grammatically correct and doesn't make much sense as is.. Maaaybe the person who wrote it tried to type/write "次回のライド**に**お誘いいただきたい次第です" which would make a little more sense, but who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 次第 is being used as a formal and polite way to mention the circumstances or reason for the desire expressed by たい.（頂きたい気持ちが湧いた、その事情のことが「次第」）

> お誘いいただきたい**次第です**。
>
> "**So** I eagerly await your invitation."

You could also say,

> お誘いいただきたい**のです**。
> お誘いいただきたい**わけです**。

with basically the same meaning, just a little less polite and formal.

Comment: I was figuring it was something like that, but I wanted to be sure! Thank you!

Comment: How could anyone answer this question when OP's sentence makes practically no sense?

Comment: I think I understood what he was getting at. No?

Comment: @sazarando Yes, You're reading is along the liens of what I had, I just wanted to be sure on the politeness level.